# AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Rails, compiled assets are not being loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am getting 400 errors for pretty much all of my assets when deploying to elastic beanstalk.

Rails v 4.2

I am toying with the idea of applying symbolic links or creating a copy ebextension but I really shouldn't have to do that.

EB uses nginx and I confirmed that nginx is serving up public/assets and public directories.

I can move a file to public/assets and it will no longer error out.

Also, the application has no issue running on ec2 instances directly.

I noticed that the browser is not attempting to load the compiled versions of my assets (ex: application-03f1fea523795448f85cf1cf62e62e6f.css) when I render the page. It tries to load the uncompiled files which are not in the public/assets directory.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please provide two things - the value of the `RACK_ENV` environment variable in your EB environment, and the corresponding configuration file from `config/environments/`?

Comment: How are those CSS being called in your HTML? Do you have used [stylesheet_link_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue. And just want to share my thoughts.

When my `RACK_ENV=development` and `RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION=false` in EB Environment properties, it correspond to the configuration file from `config/environments/development.rb` in Rails app.

And look like when I access the app from the browser, it precompile assets twice (EB precompile script, and on run-time asset compile), therefore asset hash finger will not matched. As result in, 404 assets error.